# Issue during Stellar core setup

Tags: stellar-core, nodes

**./stellar-core --genseed** command should always generate same seed or it can generate different seed. What is the logic behind executing this command?

As per my understanding , it should generate same seed always.

Answer (score 2):

The **Secret seed** is used to:

- encrypt outbound data (to be decrypted with **Public value** on the other end), and/or
- decrypt inbound data (encrypted with **Public value** on the other end).

If you want this pair to remain the same throughout *stellar-core* restarts, use the config file as the previous answer suggests. Otherwise, *stellar-core* will create a new pair for you every time it restarts. For example, using new command-line syntax,

```
alec@alec-MS-7623 ~/product/stellar-core (master) $ src/stellar-core gen-seed
Secret seed: SCX2W7O67ZDLRKRG63SWFDRBQB3SG7DT7XOEPGCDKRLWCCY3VWH3YIR3
Public: GDHHAP2JKJFH2EPTT4L5NALZZN4CKUHFGJVPWFD2472ZIROESKV7IL2H

alec@alec-MS-7623 ~/product/stellar-core (master) $ src/stellar-core gen-seed
Secret seed: SBHZ4F6XIGEPO7GL5KRD67GYJFQB3VRISOEGH6ZTE3APB57MAZOTDN4N
Public: GDXFTRDSMNPX2XQMQ3O5LFHGWJW5Y7JUZCIWJN4ETH2N6HSB6LWDQG4S

alec@alec-MS-7623 ~/product/stellar-core (master) $ src/stellar-core gen-seed
Secret seed: SBAZ442FGK2CC3SPDILN3AWKAS2K7DMCCE32ECM76O5UWZFIFWBEKCKZ
Public: GCDWSANQLOEUSBB7L3JFA2HEX7CPRVLFLECFJDIL2DB7MBV3JOELOM6P
```

Answer (score 1):

It allways generates a new random seed and I guess it's just there to have a convenient way to generate one when you are setting up a stellar-core.

Stellar-core itself generates a new random seed as nodeId on every restart, unless you define a fixed one in your config.

```
# stellar-core.cfg
# the corresponding public is your stellar-cores public key
NODE_SEED="SA3BBN6LUUS4LOHC6ZTODF..."
```